# Android Fedor's Lazy Load pass image to other activity

Tags: android, listview, lazy-loading, adapter

I m using Fedor's lazy Loader Adapter for showing images on a list view.

I want to pass the image(already downloaded) of the row which is clicked to new activity. I dont want to re download the image again.
How can this be done ?

Ref : [Lazy load of images in ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541966/android-how-do-i-do-a-lazy-load-of-images-in-listview/3068012#3068012)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fedor's Code (from what i've read) uses a File Cache aswell as a Memory Cache to Cache the downloaded files...

So Simply use

```
FileCache fileCache = new FileCache(context);
File bmp = fileCache.getFile(url);
//convert the File object to a Bitmap object using BitmapFactory (see decodeFile() method in ImageLoader)
```

and

```
MemoryCache memCache = new MemoryCache(context);
Bitmap bmp = memCache.get(url)
```

Note : If both return `null`, then you'll have to download it again.

Comment: I'm on my phone. So i dont have access to the source. But check if Imageloader has a 'getBitmap' kindof a function.

Comment: Thnx a lot , getBitmap method is wht i was looking for, works perfectly !!